# AppExchange application contents appears outside of Referenced Package folder in Eclipse

Tags: managed-package, deployment, eclipse, force.com-ide, package.xml

I have a number of applications installed in my org, and majority of them appear in the folder 'Referenced Packages' in eclipse, except for some. They appear outside of the folder 'Referenced Packages'.

How does Referenced Packages folder work? What decides which apps should be inside the Referenced packages and which should be outside?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that some of the packages you have installed are what are called "unmanaged" packages. So while they were installed via the App Exchange, they cannot be upgraded, are license free, and their code can be edited/customized by developers or admins in the org to which they've been installed. There are a large number of unmanaged packages out there that Salesforce Labs put out such as Simple/Quote/Invoice/Order and their version of Milestones-PM that work as I described.

In the case of a "managed package", it could still be "free to use", but will have its own namespace and it's primary components, particularly it's classes and triggers cannot typically be edited/customized by a customer. Some managed package components can usually be customized to suit an org's needs, but it depends on the component and the package. Those packages will be referenced in the "Referenced Packages" folder and the org's schema.

The primary purpose of that folder is that some classes, objects and pages will have dependencies on those managed packages; primarily in terms of licensing, permissions and record sharing. Those relationships need to be maintained and can affect your code along with what your code and your users have access to.

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply, i understand now what Referenced Packages folder is, my question is; how can i make an app that wont land in the Referenced Package folder when installed?

Comment: If it's an unmanaged package that doesn't have a license, it's unlikely that you'd be able to do that. Either that, or it's metadata isn't properly registered with your org., in which case you'd want to do an uninstall/reinstall to try and fix the issue. Is there an issue with it's classes and other code appearing in your project that concerns you?

Comment: A customer installed our application and it was appearing outside the Referenced Packages folder(while his other apps are inside that folder) and I was curious why that is happening. I tried to recreate the scenario ( in another org) and all the other apps are going to the Referenced Packages folder and our application is outside of it. Its a managed package with a license.

Comment: I would try a reinstall. It sounds to me as though the metadata is either not being pulled down correctly or is not registered correctly with the org. I would ask the customer if they received any errors when creating their project. I've seen a lot of metadata issues since API 35 with projects in diff orgs not being able to pull metadata correctly or completely when creating new projects. If so, they need to file a case with Salesforce.

Comment: I installed the app in another org just to confirm if something went wrong. The application folder is still outside the 'Referenced Packages' folder. All the functionality is working properly so safe to say that nothing wrong with the install. No idea why its not saving inside the 'Referenced Packages' folder. All other apps are going in that folder.

Comment: Did the metadata pull down correctly when you created your Eclipse project? Is this API 35, 36 or 37? Did your App do this before Spring 16? I'd recommend asking about this in the Partner Community and possibly filing a case on it, esp if it didn't do it before Sp16.

Comment: Yes it didn't throw any errors when the metadata was being pulled down. Never checked it before sp16.

Comment: Again, I'd highly recommend you ask this question in the Partner Community where you'll find the expertise to get a truly knowledgeable answer from within Salesforce to help you troubleshoot the issue.